# Are field embeddings unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

Sorry if this is a simple question, as I'm not well versed in field theory.

Suppose a field $K$ has an embedding into $\mathbb R$: $f:K\hookrightarrow\mathbb R$. Is $f$ unique? And if $\mathbb R$ is replaced by an arbitrary field $F$, is the answer still the same?

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227392/number-of-real-embeddings-k-to-overline-mathbb-q).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is not unique in general. For instance, there are two embeddings of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$ into $\mathbb R$.

In general, if $K=\mathbb F(\alpha)$, where $\mathbb F$ is the prime field of $K$, and $F$ is a field with the same prime field, then then number of $\mathbb F$-embeddings of $K$ into $F$ is the number of roots in $F$ of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have strengthened my premises. I know this is a different question, but if $K$ is *ordered* and $f:K\hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ is an embedding that preserves ordering, *then* is $f$ unique? I think one of the two embeddings in your counterexample wouldn't preserve order.

Comment: @WillG, ask a separate question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626904/are-order-preserving-field-embeddings-unique